# Pyspark Compare column strings, grouping if alphabetic character sets are same, but avoid similar words?

Tags: python, pyspark, count, grouping

I'm working on a project where I have a pyspark dataframe of two columns (string, string count) that are string and bigint respectively. The dataset is dirty such that some words have a non-letter character attached to them (ex. 'date', '_date', '!date' and 'date,' are all separate items but should be just 'date')

```
print(dirty_df.schema)
output---> StructType([StructField('count', LongType(), True), StructField('word', StringType(), True)])
dirty_df.show()
+------+------+
| count|  word|
+------+------+
|32375 |  date|
|359   | _date|
|306   | !date|
|213   | date,|
|209   |  snap|
|204   | ^snap|
|107   | +snap|
|12    | snap?|
```

I need to reduce the dataframe such that date, _date, !date, and date, are all just 'date' with their counts being updated to match. Problem is: I need to avoid joining on similar words like'dates', 'dating', 'dated', 'todate', etc.

**Goal**

```
+------+------+
| count|  word|
+------+------+
|33253 |  date|
|532   |  snap|
```

Any thoughts on how I could approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`regexp_replace`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_replace) function and replace all special characters`([^a-zA-Z] replace all characters other than alphabets)`.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(32375,'date'),(359,'_date'),(306,'[date'),(213,'date]'),(209,'snap'),(204,'_snap'),(107,'[snap'),(12,'snap]')],['count','word'])
df.withColumn("word",regexp_replace(col("word"),"[^a-zA-Z]","")).groupBy("word").agg(sum(col("count")).alias("count")).show(10,False)
#+----+-----+
#|word|count|
#+----+-----+
#|date|33253|
#|snap|532  |
#+----+-----+
```

---

**`Other way:`**

If you want to replace only specific characters then use **`translate`** function

```
df.withColumn("word",expr('translate(word,"(_|]|[)","")')).groupBy("word").agg(sum(col("count")).alias("count")).show(10,False)

#+----+-----+
#|word|count|
#+----+-----+
#|date|33253|
#|snap|532  |
#+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex_replace` to remove any special characters.

```
df = (df.withColumn('word', F.regexp_replace('word', '[^a-zA-Z]', ''))
      .groupby('word')
      .agg(F.sum('count').alias('count')))
```

`[^a-zA-Z]`, this regex will match any characters **other**(^ not operator) than lower and upper case alphabets.